# Using sympy to solve a two-sided inequality with absolute value

Tags: sympy, inequality, absolute-value

Relatively simple math problem, find the range over which `3 <= Abs[6 - x] <= 5`. Not hard to solve by hand, and Mathematica nails it, with the answer `1 <= x <= 3 || 9 <= x <= 11`.

The closest I can get with sympy is

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x', real=True)
reduce_inequalities([3 <= abs(6 - x), abs(6 - x) <= 5], x)
```

This results in

```
1≤∧≤11∧(9≤∨≤3)
```

which, if I read it correctly, is sympy's way of saying

```
1 <= x || x< 11 || (9 <= x || x <= 3)
```

which is both odd and wrong. What am I missing here?

Comment: `∧` is And, not OR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the output from SymPy:

```
In [1]: from sympy import *
   ...: x = symbols('x', real=True)
   ...: reduce_inequalities([3 <= abs(6 - x), abs(6 - x) <= 5], x)
Out[1]: 1 ≤ x ∧ x ≤ 11 ∧ (9 ≤ x ∨ x ≤ 3)
```

What this means is that `1 <= x <= 11` AND (`x >= 9` OR `x <= 3`).

This is logically equivalent to the Mathematica output that you refer to although perhaps not expressed as clearly. You can manipulate the output to the same form with:

```
In [2]: r = reduce_inequalities([3 <= abs(6 - x), abs(6 - x) <= 5], x)

In [3]: r.as_set()
Out[3]: [1, 3] ∪ [9, 11]

In [4]: r.as_set().as_relational(x)
Out[4]: (1 ≤ x ∧ x ≤ 3) ∨ (9 ≤ x ∧ x ≤ 11)
```